# Google Drive upload from webserver

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a service that runs on a webserver and can upload files to Google Drive,
so that people can sync the files to local-drive using the Google desktop application.

So I tried the Drive API but it requires a webbrowser to authenticate.
This would be a possibility, but I don't know to get the access token programmically.
Even if I had the access token, I wouldn't know if it just works forever.. It seems to have an expire date?
I wouldn't want the service to suddenly not working, because the token has expired.

Than I learned about Service Account, and finally got it working, but it seems to have its own space that i can only access with the service account.
I don't know how to share the files from the service account to a regular account, as people need to sync it locally.

So a found a video about user impersonation, in which he showed a page about given access to a service account to impersonate another user.
But i don't know where to find this page.
Looking at: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106&topic=2759255&ctx=topic
It says it's in Advanced Tools > Manage third party OAuth client access (under the Authentication section).
But where is the Authentication section? Do I need to create a Google App to do this?

The question is: How upload files programmically to Google Drive without any user intervention, so that they can be synced locally with the drive desktop-application.